# Error in the returned jsonp

Tags: ajax, json

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://api.xhanch.com/islamic-get-prayer-time.php?lng=34.4366455078125&lat=31.48957771850194&yy=2013&mm=5&gmt=3&m=json',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function () {
        console.log('Success!');
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log('Uh Oh!');
    },
    jsonp: 'jsonp'
});
```

when I run this code I get an error in the return json object

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token:

Why?

Comment: What does it say after 'Unexpected token:'?

Comment: It doesn't look like that API supports JSONP.

Comment: nothing it gives me a link to the file that contains the error

Comment: @Barmar so how I can get the data from it without having the cross origin problem?

Comment: You need to use a proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `jsonp: 'jsonp'` is calling the method `jsonp` that doesn't exist in your code. If you really need this, just create the method or remove it.

#### Remove

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://api.xhanch.com/islamic-get-prayer-time.php?lng=34.4366455078125&lat=31.48957771850194&yy=2013&mm=5&gmt=3&m=json',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function () {
        console.log('Success!');
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log('Uh Oh!');
    },
});
```

#### Or create the method

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://api.xhanch.com/islamic-get-prayer-time.php?lng=34.4366455078125&lat=31.48957771850194&yy=2013&mm=5&gmt=3&m=json',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function () {
        console.log('Success!');
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log('Uh Oh!');
    },
    jsonp: { jsonp: false, jsonpCallback: "callbackName" }
});

function callbackName(){
   /*do something*/
}
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

#### jsonp

> Type: String Override the callback function name in a jsonp request.
>   This value will be used instead of 'callback' in the 'callback=?' part
>   of the query string in the url. So {jsonp:'onJSONPLoad'} would result
>   in 'onJSONPLoad=?' passed to the server. As of jQuery 1.5, setting the
>   jsonp option to false prevents jQuery from adding the "?callback"
>   string to the URL or attempting to use "=?" for transformation. In
>   this case, you should also explicitly set the jsonpCallback setting.
>   For example, { jsonp: false, jsonpCallback: "callbackName" }

Comment: If it's jsonp and clearly getting data from a different domain, does this need that "?callback=?" shim in the URL ?

Comment: jQuery adds that automatically when you specify JSONP dataType.

Comment: I usually don't put this attribute but I was trying it .